# I need a mysql query (import/export) formula for Prestashop products

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, prestashop

I have a shop running on 1.7.5.2 and I decided to upgrade to 1.7.6 but what I want to do is to install also a new theme and get rid of all old modules, so I decided the best option is to Install a fresh new PS 1.7.6 onto a provisional subdomain and transfer Categories, Attibutes and Products with all images combinations...etc from 1.7.5.2 to 1.7.6 then to apply the new theme.

The problem is I;m not shure what MYSQL tables to export and import into new one.

Can anyone tell me which tables from mysql database I should export and then import into new installation ?
Or what MYSQL code to run for export / import required tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to export all orders, customers, addresses, products, images tables.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this was the first thing I tried but without luck.